# Send email each month based on values in CRM 3

Tags: email, crm, microsoft-dynamics

My company is using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 3, and I'm having some trouble setting up an automatic email. My manager wants to have it setup so that if we bill our customer on the 15th of the month, we send an email out on the 14th, and if it's on the 1st, we send one out the 30th/31st, etc. etc.

I've come across a few helpful things, but my issue is I don't have access to the actual code for the CRM - if it's the only way, it's the only way, but for now I've been trying to setup workflows, but those can only be ran manually - it wouldn't be a MAJOR issue, but then we would have to choose the people to email it to every month, etc etc. I also tried a marketing list, but that doesn't let me send out emails, unless it's through a quick campaign.

Does anyone know of a built in way in CRM 3 to setup automatic emailing each month to a group of customers with a similar value in a particular textbox?

Comment: In Dynamics CRM 4 you can schedule a custom workflow activity to run at a predefined time, but I can't confirm this feature is present in version 3, even if it seems very basic.. You can also trigger the execution when some event arise.

Comment: I tried the custom workflow activity, but maybe I missed something - I'll go back and double check... otherwise, if I can't set the workflow to do _____ at a predefined time, maybe I can create a task that happens at a predefined time, and then run the workflow off of that task --- thanks, I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: I guess we ARE using 4.0 --- sorry about that --- but I can't find out how to run the workflow at the predefined time - I get the options for  Start when 'Record is created','Record status changes', 'Record is assigned','Record attributes change', etc...  Am I looking in the wrong area? I'm in Workflow Information - General

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had done this sometime ago, you're right, there is not such "scheduled workflow" in CRM 4, but you can simulate this behavior using two workflows, one calling another when the former times out as condition. The first time you have to invoke it manually. Give me some time to find the virtual machine where this project is hosted for more details.